# Turn off echo IO::Socket::INET

Tags: perl, sockets

I am trying to create a remote-login script with perl. I am currently getting input data using

```
$var = <$client>; 
chomp $var;
```

However, I am trying to have the client input a password and I want to hide the password in the linux fashion with the client by not echoing what is typed. Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT:

```
$serv = IO::Socket::INET->new ( 
Proto => 'tcp',
LocalPort => $port,
Listen => 10,
Reuse => 1)
|| die "Can't create server: $!";

while ($client = $serv->accept()) {
eval {
$client->autoflush(1); # Always remember to flush!
$who = $client->peerhost;
print STDERR "Connection from $who\n";
print $client hostname . " login: ";
$usr = <$client>;
chomp $usr;
$usr =~ s/\W//g;
print STDERR "User $usr\n";
die unless (length $usr < 20 && length $usr > 1);
print $client "Encrypted Password: ";
$pass = <$client>;
chomp $pass;
die unless (length $pass < 20 && length $pass > 1);
print STDERR "$who: Pass $pass\n";
};
close $client;
}
```

Comment: Sockets don't echo. This has nothing to do with sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is local console echo, nothing to do with your socket.

There are many ways to turn off console echo using Perl, but my favourite is `IO::Termios` (perhaps I'm biased because I wrote it ;) )

```
use IO::Termios;
my $stdin = IO::Termios->new(\*STDIN);
$stdin->setflag_echo(0);
```